# Wrong Point Cloud orientation in Rviz

Tags: gazebo, rviz, transform, pointcloud, ros-noetic

I am trying to correctly orient the pointcloud data coming from a Depth camera sensor Gazebo model into the Rviz, but it's not working.

Camera Model:

```
<gazebo reference="camera_link_1">
        <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
        <sensor name="camera" type="depth">
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
            <visualize>true</visualize>
            <update_rate>30</update_rate>
            <camera>
                <horizontal_fov>1.089</horizontal_fov>
                <image>
                    <format>B8G8R8</format>
                    <width>640</width>
                    <height>480</height>
                </image>
                <clip>
                    <near>0.05</near>
                    <far>5.0</far>
                </clip>
                 <noise>
                   <type>gaussian</type>
          <!-- Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.
               That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
               channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. -->
                   <mean>0.0</mean>
                   <stddev>0.035</stddev>
                </noise>
              </camera>
    <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
        <baseline>0.2</baseline>
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <!-- Keep this zero, update_rate in the parent <sensor> tag
          will control the frame rate. -->
        <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>ur5_1/</cameraName>
        <imageTopicName>/ur5/depth/image_raw_1</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>/ur5/depth/camera_info_1</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <depthImageTopicName>/ur5/depth/image_raw_1</depthImageTopicName>
        <depthImageInfoTopicName>/ur5/depth/camera_info_1</depthImageInfoTopicName>
        <pointCloudTopicName>/ur5/depth/points_1</pointCloudTopicName>
        <frameName>camera_link_1</frameName>
        <min_depth>0.1</min_depth>
        <max_depth>50.0</max_depth>
        <pointCloudCutoff>0.05</pointCloudCutoff>
        <distortionK1>0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0</distortionT2>
        <CxPrime>0</CxPrime>
        <Cx>0</Cx>
        <Cy>0</Cy>
        <focalLength>0</focalLength>
        <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
    <joint name="camera_world_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world" />
    <child link = "camera_link_1" />
    <origin xyz="0.9 -0.079916 2.00" rpy="0.0 1.20 3.14" />
  </joint>
```

[image]

[image]

I would really appreciate some help/guidance on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ros, the convention for camera-like devices is to orient the "optical frame" so that +x points right, +y points down, and the +z points forward (toward the scene.)

One method to get the correct TF tree is to add a fixed joint from the camera_frame to the camera_optical_frame; this joint bends the z-axis from "up" to "forward". The usual rpy used **for a joint** is "-1.570796 0 -1.570796".

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment, so i am writing in the answer section.
Can you try to change the frame (from base link to __camera link)in rviz and check the orientation again?

Comment: I already tried that but the problem remains same.

Comment: what is the error in rviz under camera tab. It shows yellow

Comment: Its camera Warning but it is not related to orientation of point cloud.

Comment: is it possible to add urdf file or link to github repo?